# When do the ItemRealized / ItemUnrealized events of LongListSelector trigger exactly?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to implement infinite scrolling using 'LongListSelector' and the 'ItemRealized' / 'ItemUnrealized' events. I'm using an 'ObservableCollection' which at any time contains the "realized" elements plus 'Offset' elements at the start and end of the collection, this guarantees that the collection contains only a fixed amount of elements.

Here's the code for my 'FixList' function which I call after each 'ItemRealized' / 'ItemUnrealized' event:

```
    void FixList()
    {
        while (Math.Max(0, ItemList.Count - LoadedEnd) > Offset)
        {
            ItemList.RemoveAt(ItemList.Count - 1);
            SourceEnd--;
        }

        while (Math.Max(0, ItemList.Count - LoadedEnd) < Offset)
        {
            ItemList.Add(DataSource.GetCell((uint)SourceEnd));
            SourceEnd++;
        }

        while (LoadedStart >= Offset)
        {
            ItemList.RemoveAt(0);
            SourceStart++;
            LoadedStart--;
            LoadedEnd--;
        }

        while (LoadedStart < Offset - 1 && SourceStart > 0)
        {
            ItemList.Insert(0, DataSource.GetCell((uint)SourceStart - 1));
            SourceStart--;
            LoadedStart++;
            LoadedEnd++;
        }
    }
```

Where 'LoadedStart' / 'LoadedEnd' are the indices of the "realized" elements in my collection and 'SourceStart' / 'SourceEnd' are indices I use to retrieve elements from my DataSource.

Here is the order of the 'LongListSelector' event I get when the app starts:

```
load Test 0
load Test 1
load Test 2
load Test 3
load Test 4
load Test 5
load Test 6
load Test 7
load Test 8
load Test 9
load Test 10
load Test 11
load Test 12
load Test 13
load Test 14
load Test 15
load Test 16
Unload Test 16
Unload Test 15
load Test 10
load Test 11
load Test 12
load Test 13
load Test 14
Unload Test 14
Unload Test 13
Unload Test 12
Unload Test 11
Unload Test 10
load Test 15
load Test 16
load Test 17
load Test 18
load Test 19
load Test 20
load Test 21
load Test 22
load Test 23
```

which seems completely illogical considering that I'm not even scrolling (illogical in a sense that it loads and unloads the same elements multiple times).

The weird thing is that this only happens at startup, when I scrolld down a bit, the events seem to trigger properly (an element unloads when it's not anymore needed and loads when it's about to get viewed).